# Why does delete[] work in one case but not another?

Tags: c++, arrays

Could someone explain to me how `delete[]` works in the function below?

Specifically, `arr = arrtemp; delete[] arrtemp;` fails, but `delete[] arr; arr = arrtemp` works.

```
void AddElement(int *&arr, int &n, int pos, int val){
    int *arrtemp = new int[n + 1];
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= pos; i++){
        *(arrtemp + i) = *(arr + i);
    }
    for(int i = pos; i < n; i++){
        *(arrtemp + i + 1) = *(arr + i);
    }
    *(arrtemp + pos) = val;
    n++;
    
    //This works just fine
    delete[] arr;
    arr = arrtemp;

    //But this one fails
    //arr = arrtemp;
    // delete[] arrtemp;
}
```

My thought was that I assign `arr = arrtemp` so that pointer `arr` now points to the added array, and I `delete[] arrtemp` should have no effect on `arr`, but it does @@ and I don't know why.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why you *think* the two should be equivalent. In one case, you delete the array called `arrtemp`. In the other case, you delete the array called `arr`

Comment: please post code that fails, say what failure you are getting, its hard to follow which is which in the code you have posted.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but `*(arr + i)` is usually written `arr[i]`.

Comment: and it would be nice if it had the calling main too so a) we can test it b) the problem might be there

Comment: If you did `arr = arrtemp; delete[] arrtemp;` you would delete the array that `arr` points to (both arrtemp and arr point to the same location) and leak the previous array.

Comment: Nitpick: You _can_ write `*(arrtemp + pos) = val;` but don't. Use `arrtemp[pos] = val;` instead.

Comment: Please define what "fails" means in the context of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My thought was that I assign `arr = arrtemp` so that pointer `arr` now points to the added array, and I `delete[] arrtemp` should have no effect on `arr`,

Strictly speaking, this much is true. However, if you take this viewpoint, then strictly speaking, `delete[] arrtemp` should have no effect on `arrtemp`. Deleting the memory to which `arrtemp` points does not change `arrtemp`; it still points to the same memory location. What has changed is that accessing that memory is no longer valid.

> but it does

Strictly speaking, this is false. Deleting the memory to which `arrtemp` points has no effect on `arr`. And that likely accounts for the symptoms you are seeing. There is no effect on `arr`, so `arr` still points to the same memory as before the deletion, to the same memory to which `arrtemp` points, to the memory that is no longer valid to access because it has been deleted.

Before the deletion:

```
-----------
| arr     |---\
-----------   |
              |    --------------------
 same address |--->| allocated memory | valid to access
              |    --------------------
-----------   |
| arrtemp |---/
-----------
```

After the deletion:

```
-----------
| arr     |---\
-----------   |
              |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 same address |--->(  deleted memory    ) invalid to access
              |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-----------   |
| arrtemp |---/
-----------
```

There is no change to `arr` (the pointer), but there is a change to `*arr` (the pointed-to object). This distinction is important. When `arr == arrtemp`, then deleting `*arrtemp` also deletes `*arr`. The situation is not merely that `*arr` is equivalent to `*arrtemp`, but that `*arr` **is** `*arrtemp`. Two names for the same object. Calling `delete[] arrtemp` directs the computer to delete the array (starting at) `*arrtemp`, a.k.a. `*arr` in your situation. Accessing that array after the deletion is invalid, regardless of which name you use to access the array.

Answer (score 1):

`arr = arrtemp;` assigns one pointer to another. Nothing is copied. `delete[] arrtemp` deletes the memory pointed to by `arrtemp`. Since `arr` and `arrtemp` point to the same place, the memory that *both* pointers point to has been freed and is no longer usable.

Answer (score 0):

**Working scenario**

- arr -    has address 'A' which it got from caller
- arrtemp - has address 'B'

```
    delete[] arr;   // deleted 'A'
    arr = arrtemp;  // assigned addr 'B' to arr;
```

- arr caller has still valid but address of arrtemp. Hence it is working

**In wrong scenario**

- arr -    has address 'A' which it got from caller
- arrtemp - has address 'B'

```
     arr = arrtemp;  // arr has address 'B'
     delete[] arrtemp; // deleted 'B'
```

so address on arr is deleted. Assign just the value to **arr** from **arrtemp** and not address.